# Eclipse plugin development : How to listen events in Eclipse editor

Tags: eclipse, events, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-pde, eclipse-jdt

I am trying to develop an eclipse plug-in. I am aware about the basics of this thing.

In a sample plugin template when we click the menu entry (or button with eclipse icon in below image in this case) in testing instance of eclipse, **execute** method of **sampleHandler.java** is executed and a pop-up shown in image below appears.

[image]

I want to invoke 'execute' method whenever I press some key (lets say backspace) in code editor instead of clicking any menu entry (or button).

**SampleHandler.java**

```java
 public class SampleHandler extends AbstractHandler {

    public SampleHandler() {
    }

    /**
     * the command has been executed, so extract extract the needed information
     * from the application context.
     */
    public Object execute(ExecutionEvent event) throws ExecutionException {
        IWorkbenchWindow window = HandlerUtil.getActiveWorkbenchWindowChecked(event);
        MessageDialog.openInformation(
                window.getShell(),
                "Sdfsdfsadf",
                "Hello, Eclipse world");
        return null;
    }
   }
```

I tried suggestions given in [other posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11485082/eclipse-plugin-to-granularly-monitor-editor-changes?rq=1) but I am unable to achieve the desired functionality.

As per my understanding from referenced post in above line, I tried below code -

```java
    package eventlisten.handlers;

import org.eclipse.core.commands.AbstractHandler;
import org.eclipse.core.commands.ExecutionEvent;
import org.eclipse.core.commands.ExecutionException;
import org.eclipse.ui.IEditorInput;
import org.eclipse.ui.IEditorPart;
import org.eclipse.ui.IWorkbenchPage;
import org.eclipse.ui.IWorkbenchWindow;
import org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI;


import org.eclipse.ui.handlers.HandlerUtil;
import org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.ITextEditor;
import org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.MessageDialog;
import org.eclipse.jface.text.DocumentEvent;
import org.eclipse.jface.text.IDocument;
import org.eclipse.jface.text.IDocumentListener;

/**
 * Our sample handler extends AbstractHandler, an IHandler base class.
 * @see org.eclipse.core.commands.IHandler
 * @see org.eclipse.core.commands.AbstractHandler
 */
public class SampleHandler extends AbstractHandler {
    /**
     * The constructor.
     */
    public SampleHandler() {
    }

    /**
     * the command has been executed, so extract extract the needed information
     * from the application context.
     */
    public Object execute(ExecutionEvent event) throws ExecutionException {

        IWorkbenchWindow window = HandlerUtil.getActiveWorkbenchWindowChecked(event);
        MessageDialog.openInformation(window.getShell(),"EventListen","Trying event listen");
        IWorkbenchPage page = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage();
        IEditorPart editor = page.getActiveEditor();
        IEditorInput input = editor.getEditorInput();  
        IDocument document=(((ITextEditor)editor).getDocumentProvider()).getDocument(IDocument.class);

        document.addDocumentListener(new IDocumentListener() //**this is line 45**
        {
            @Override
            public void documentAboutToBeChanged(DocumentEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                System.out.println("Hello");
            }

            @Override
            public void documentChanged(DocumentEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                System.out.println("Hello second");

            }
        });

        return null;
    }
}
```

But after showing the pop-up , it throws the exception -

```java
java.lang.NullPointerException
at eventlisten.handlers.SampleHandler.execute(SampleHandler.java:45)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerProxy.execute(HandlerProxy.java:290)
at org.eclipse.core.commands.Command.executeWithChecks(Command.java:499)
at org.eclipse.core.commands.ParameterizedCommand.executeWithChecks(ParameterizedCommand.java:508)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerService.executeCommand(HandlerService.java:169)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.SlaveHandlerService.executeCommand(SlaveHandlerService.java:241)
at org.eclipse.ui.menus.CommandContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(CommandContributionItem.java:829)
at org.eclipse.ui.menus.CommandContributionItem.access$19(CommandContributionItem.java:815)
at org.eclipse.ui.menus.CommandContributionItem$5.handleEvent(CommandContributionItem.java:805)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1276)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3562)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3186)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2701)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2665)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2499)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:679)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:668)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)
```

Can someone guide me through the process? Let me know in case more information is required.

Comment: You refer to another question and answer, but what specifically did you try and what results did you achieve or fail to achieve?

Comment: Updated the post. I don't even know how to proceed using that post's code.

Comment: Do you really want to run the execute every time when the user presses a key or just if the content changes (or is it even enough when the file is saved)?
Is the `document==null`? You can test this by setting a breakpoint on linek 43, start the plug-in in debug mode and run the line 43 (F6 or step over in the toolbar) and then hover over `document`.
Or can you say specifically what instance is `null`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your first problem seems to be that you only interact with the documents when the user presses the button.  There are better ways to set this up.
As far as I can tell, you want to either detect when a user modifies a document (probably by typing),  any key is typed anywhere, or when the [AST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree) of the code is modified.  You will probably only find **one** of the solutions below useful or relevant.

**Listening to Document Changes**

The solution you attempted is closest to the first one, so I'll start there.  I did something like this (in the post you linked, as it turns out).  Start by making your plugin extend the    org.eclipse.ui.startup extension point, and define a class to override [IStartup](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fui%2FIStartup.html)

That `earlyStartup()` will look something like:

```java
@Override
public void earlyStartup() {
    IWorkbench wb = PlatformUI.getWorkbench();
    wb.addWindowListener(generateWindowListener());
}
```

We'll listen for windows to open, and when they do,

```java
private IWindowListener generateWindowListener() 
{
    return new IWindowListener() {
        @Override
        public void windowOpened(IWorkbenchWindow window) {
            IWorkbenchPage activePage = window.getActivePage(); 
            activePage.addPartListener(generateIPartListener2());
        }

        @Override
        public void windowDeactivated(IWorkbenchWindow window) {}

        @Override
        public void windowClosed(IWorkbenchWindow window) {}

        @Override
        public void windowActivated(IWorkbenchWindow window) {}
    };
}
```

This part listener is where you should get the `EditorPart`, which means you can add the document listener:

```java
private IPartListener2 generateIPartListener2() 
{
    return new IPartListener2() {

        private void checkPart(IWorkbenchPartReference partRef) {
        IWorkbenchPart part = partRef.getPart(false);
            if (part instanceof IEditorPart)
            {
                IEditorPart editor = (IEditorPart) part;
                IEditorInput input = editor.getEditorInput();
                if (editor instanceof ITextEditor && input instanceof FileEditorInput)  //double check.  Error Editors can also bring up this call
                {
                    IDocument document=(((ITextEditor)editor).getDocumentProvider()).getDocument(input);
                    document.addDocumentListener(/* your listener from above*/);
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void partOpened(IWorkbenchPartReference partRef) {
            checkPart(partRef);
        }

        @Override
        public void partInputChanged(IWorkbenchPartReference partRef) 
        {
            checkPart(partRef);
        }           

        @Override
        public void partVisible(IWorkbenchPartReference partRef){}

        @Override
        public void partHidden(IWorkbenchPartReference partRef) {}

        @Override
        public void partDeactivated(IWorkbenchPartReference partRef)  {}

        @Override
        public void partClosed(IWorkbenchPartReference partRef) {}

        @Override
        public void partBroughtToTop(IWorkbenchPartReference partRef) {}

        @Override
        public void partActivated(IWorkbenchPartReference partRef) {}
    };
}
```

**Listening to just the keypressess**

This ends up being simpler to implement, but may be very noisy.  We'll be looking at the [Display](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Display.html) and the [Listener](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Listener.html), which gets right into the SWT event loop.

You'll want to do the earlyStartup() extension again, and have something like:

```java
@Override
public void earlyStartup() {
    Display display = Display.getDefault();
    display.setFilter(SWT.KeyUp, new Listener() {
        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event event) {
            //do stuff here.  Be careful, this may cause lag
        }
     });
}
```

**Listening to Java AST changes**
The final one has the simplicity of the raw keyup approach, but will probably be as semantically useful as the first one I suggested.  We will be listening to the [JavaCore](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jdt/core/JavaCore.html) directly.

Again, in the earlyStartup method()

```java
 JavaCore.addElementChangedListener(new IElementChangedListener() {

        @Override
        public void elementChanged(ElementChangedEvent event)
        {
            //do stuff with the event
        }
    });
```

**Conclusion**:  With luck, one of these three methods is useful to you.  I've had reason to use each in my Eclipse development career -- each is useful in its own way.

I hope this helps.