# How to listen to changes in Java editor to refresh a view part?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm implementing an Eclipse plug-in to refresh a new view part when any change occurs in a Java file. Is this possible? And how?

Besides that, I need to identify the abstract syntax tree (AST) of the present code in the Java editor. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can listen to changes of the underlying `IDocument` as described here: [Eclipse Plugin to granularly monitor editor changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11485082/eclipse-plugin-to-granularly-monitor-editor-changes)

The Java editor input also adapts to `IJavaElement`. For example:

```java
editor.getEditorInput().getAdapter( IJavaElement.class )
```

If the result is an `ICompilationUnit`, you can create an AST thereof as described here: https://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-JavaCodeManipulation_AST/index.html